# Why doesn't "I want to go home" use идти?

Tags: грамматика

The Russian for "I want to go home" is "Я хочу домой", which obviously uses хочу (want) but not идти (to go).

However, the Russian for "I want home" is also "я хочу домой".

Why is that? Is it just a quirk of the language or can хочу serve as shorthand for other words as well?

Comment: I should say that two sentences, "Я хочу домой" and "Я хочу идти домой" are slightly different in meaning. The former expresses an *emotion* - "I am missing home". It is not necessarily associated with the *intent* to go. For example, you could say this as a prisoner, a refugee, amidst a long business trip, and so on. You could also say that on an ordinary day if you're tired and annoyed, yearning to get to a place where you can be comfortable. The latter expresses a direct *intent*. In particular, the verb you choose - идти, ехать, лететь etc. - expresses how you intend to get home.

Answer (score 5):

You can translate "I want to go home" as "Я хочу пойти домой" as well.
I guess this is common between English and Russian: the verb after "want" can be omitted if it is obvious.

I want to eat a sandwich. I want a sandwich. Я хочу съесть бутерброд. Я хочу бутерброд.

I want to buy a new phone. I want a new phone. Я хочу купить новый телефон. Я хочу новый телефон.

Comment: Besides, "домо́й" itself implies movement "to home" vs до́ма "at home".

Answer (score 4):

In speech, you can omit verbs if the context is clear: "Я хочу (поехать) к бабушке", "Я хочу (купить, получить на день рождения) новый диван".

However, you shouldn't use "идти" in this particular case, since this verb is imperfective and you put an unnecessary emphasis on the process of walking home (Я хочу идти домой = I want to get home by foot, not by bus).

If you must, use a perfective verb - "Я хочу уйти домой"; still, this sounds like "I don't like it here" or "I have something important to do at home".

However, if you add some context, it's better to use a verb: "Я хочу уйти домой пораньше".

Comment: See also https://ru.hinative.com/questions/13407217#answer-32145555 for the difference between "уйти" and "пойти".